# multiplicity of functions

Tags: complex-analysis, riemann-surfaces

I'm reading Forster's riemann surfaces book and l have problem with the meaning of multiplicity, can someone give an example to show how we can compute multiplicity of any functions,not just polynomial functions?[image][image]

Comment: There's no such thing as multiplicity of a function. There is such a thing as the multiplicity of a zero of a function $f$ at a point $z$; if $f$ and all of its derivatives up to but not including the $n$th derivative vanish at $z$, then $f$ has a zero of multiplicity $n$ at $z$.

Comment: That's right,but can the above remark have the same meaning as you said? and could you please explain the example 2.3? Thanks a lot.

Comment: OK, so that paragraph doesn't define the multiplicity of $f$, but the multiplicity of $f$ *at the point* $a$. It's a generalization of the notion of multiplicity I gave in my comment. 2.3 says that if $f$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ and if $f(a)=b$ for $a,b$ in some neighborhoods of infinity then there are exactly $k$ solutions of $f(z)=b$ in some appropriate neighborhood of infinity.

Comment: Yes,but I don't understand why is exactly k solution,and in particular l don't know how we can compute multiplicity of a function at a point or could you please give another example about this concept?

Comment: In the case of polynomials, it's exactly $k$ solutions because a polynomial equation of degree $k$ over an algebraically closed field has exactly $k$ solutions. In the general case it's exactly $k$ solutions because it's defined that way – if it doesn't have exactly $k$ solutions, the function doesn't have multiplicity $k$ at that point. To compute multiplicity of $f$ at $a$ I suppose you have to work out how many solutions $f(z)=b$ has near $a$ for values of $b$ near $f(a)$. E.g., the multiplicity of $f(z)=\cos z$ at zero would be the number of solutions near zero (continued)

Comment: (continued) of $\cos z=b$ for values of $b$ near $1$. $\cos z=.99$ has two solutions with $z$ near zero, suggesting multiplicity two. By the way, if you want to be sure I am notified of a comment intended for me, you have to include @Gerry in it.

Comment: Did that help, Hanieh?

Comment: It's not very obvious  to me to for instance in E.g. 2.3 the multiplicity of f at infinity is k ,I read in a lecture note that this remark give us a geometrical view and we can't compute with it ,but if we use the first part of the proof of theorem ( that I added in question) we can understand what is the multiplicity ,but how does it work for E.g.2.3? Thanks a lot for your helps.

Comment: It said we should factorize it (like in the proof) , but I don't know how to continue with it.

Comment: You forgot to include @Gerry in your comment. I don't know what you mean by "factorize it". $f(z)=z^k+c_1z^{k-1}+\cdots+c_k=z^kg(z)$ where $g(z)=1+c_1z^{-1}+\cdots+c_kz^{-k}$ is holomorphic in a neighborhood of $\infty$, with $g(\infty)\ne0$, so $g=h^k$ for some function $h$ holomorphic in a neighborhood of $\infty$. Then the last few lines of the proof of 2.1 tell you how to go from there to charts $\psi$ and $\phi$ such that $(\psi\circ f\circ\phi^{-1})(z)=z^k$. But I'm not sure I've understood & answered your question. Maybe you should speak to your teacher.

Comment: excuse me,I forgot to include @Gerry in my comment. Thanks for your explanations,  It become more obvious for me.